# Why clientside oauth is bad?

Tags: javascript, http, web, twitter, oauth

I've heard that making oauth requests right from client is bad. And there should be server proxy for that purpose. But could you explain in details why?

P.S. as I can see in network tab, site https://tweetdeck.twitter.com/ sends requests to api.twitter.com right from client.

Thanks for advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the exact details of why Tweet Deck sends requests to `api.twitter.com` directly, but I can answer *why* you shouldn't do this in almost all cases: **because OAuth may involve exchanging *client secrets* that you don't want to share with the rest of the world**.

Thus, you proxy requests from the client to your own server because you want to keep *secrets* from client's eyes and authorize requests behind the scenes.